# MS Access VBA unable to create new Table obj in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am having issues with making a new table in an excel spreadsheet from a VBA module in Access.

Here is my code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub QueryExportMod()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\ExportExcelTest.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$20:$B$21"), , xlYes).Name = "tb2"

xlApp.Visible = True

xlApp.Run "callAG"

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

The line that is giving me issues is `ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$20:$B$21"), , xlYes).Name = "tb2"`

I am getting runtime error 5: "invalid procedure call or argument." I wrote this line based on the actual VBA documentation. I also recorded a macro for creating the table in Excel and got the exact same line.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You are opening the workbook and the worksheet twice. And your ranges aren't qualified; define them to belong to the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gustav. I apologize, the extra sub at the bottom was just something I tried, I edited the code to fix. How can I make sure my ranges are qualified?

Comment: figured out how to qualify the range, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

solved issue -- range was not qualified.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws.Range(A20:B21)

ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "tb2"
```